# Coq: Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix

Tags: coq, coqide

I am trying to write a function that executes boolean operations in a stack program. So far I have got the code bellow but, for some reason, `executeBool` doesn't work. Coq shows the error "Cannot guess decreasing argument of fix" but I'm not quite sure why since it seems a bit "obvious" that is it `program`.

```
Require Import ZArith.
Require Import List.
Require Import Recdef.
Require Import Coq.FSets.FMaps.
Require Import Coq.Strings.String.

Module Import M := FMapList.Make(String_as_OT). 

Set Implicit Arguments.
Open Scope Z_scope. 
Open Scope string_scope.

Inductive insStBool : Type :=
  | SBPush    : Z -> insStBool
  | SBLoad    : string -> insStBool
  | SBNeg     : insStBool
  | SBCon     : insStBool
  | SBDis     : insStBool
  | SBEq      : insStBool
  | SBLt      : insStBool
  | SBSkip    : nat -> insStBool.

Definition getVal (s:string) (st:M.t Z) : Z := 
  match (find s st) with 
    | Some val => val
    | None     => 0
  end.

Fixpoint executeBool (state:M.t Z) (stack:list Z) (program:list insStBool) : list Z :=
  match program with 
    | nil              => stack
    | (SBPush n)::l    => executeBool state (n::stack) l
    | (SBLoad x)::l    => executeBool state ((getVal x state)::stack) l
    | (SBNeg)::l       => match stack with 
                            | nil   => nil
                            | 0::st => executeBool state (1::st) l
                            | _::st => executeBool state (0::st) l
                          end
    | (SBCon)::(SBSkip n)::l  => match stack with 
                                      | nil   => nil 
                                      | 0::st => executeBool state (0::st) ((SBSkip n)::l)
                                      | _::st => executeBool state st l
                                 end
    | (SBDis)::(SBSkip n)::l  => match l with 
                                  | nil  => nil
                                  | m::k =>
                                    match stack with 
                                      | nil   => nil 
                                      | 0::st => executeBool state st l
                                      | _::st => executeBool state (1::st) ((SBSkip n)::l)
                                    end
                                 end
    | (SBSkip n)::m::l => match n with 
                            | 0%nat => executeBool state stack (m::l)
                            | (S k) => executeBool state stack ((SBSkip k)::l)
                          end
    | (SBEq)::l        => match stack with 
                            | nil      => nil 
                            | n::nil   => nil 
                            | n::m::st => match (m - n) with 
                                            | 0 => executeBool state (1::st) l
                                            | _ => executeBool state (0::st) l
                                          end
                          end  
    | (SBLt)::l        => match stack with 
                            | nil      => nil 
                            | n::nil   => nil 
                            | n::m::st => match (m - n) with 
                                            | Z.pos x => executeBool state (1::st) l
                                            | _       => executeBool state (0::st) l
                                          end
                          end
    | _ => nil
    end.
```

Why does this happen? No matter how much I change the function, I keep getting it... Is there any way to fix it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few recursive calls to `executeBool` that are not called directly on a subterm of progam but on a term that you rebuilt out of subterms for instance `executeBool state (0::st) ((SBSkip n)::l)`. The solution is to make explicit that `(SBSkip n)::l` is a subterm of program by writing the corresponding match case with an `as` clause capturing that subterm

```
match program with
...
| (SBCon)::(((SBSkip n)::l) as l')  => ... executeBool state (0::st) l'
...
```

In order to understand where Coq is having troubles, you could also have added an explicit `struct` clause to your definition to indicate which parameter should be decreasing (it can also lead to better performances with large fixpoints):

```
Fixpoint executeBool (state:M.t Z) (stack:list Z) (program:list insStBool) {struct program} : list Z := ...
```

Finally, as a rule of thumb for future questions, please try to minimize the examples that you post and make sure that they have all the necessary imports to reproduce your problem (e.g. `M.t` is not defined, the imports for `Z` and for list notations are missing).

Answer (score 1):

`program` is technically decreasing, but you use it with syntactically a constructor added and Coq's decreasing check is not very smart. Try to give the subelements in the match a name with `as` and use this name as in:

```
    | (SBCon)::((SBSkip n)::l as l') => match stack with 
                                      | nil   => nil 
                                      | 0::st => executeBool state (0::st) (l')
                                      | _::st => executeBool state st l
```